# Wordpress previous_post_link() and next_post_link() don't work at CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

everyone!

There is a problem at Wordpress with CPT and ACF.

I have ACF fields ('previouspost' and 'nextpost) at my CPT "portfolio" posts. I need every post to get previous and next post links to ACF fields. Code, which I use don't make anything, fields are empty, no errors and warnings

```
function update_portolio_metadata(){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio', // Only get the posts
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Only the posts that are published
        'posts_per_page'   => -1 // Get every post
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $previouslink = previous_post_link();
            $nextlink = next_post_link();


    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'previouspost', $previouslink);
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nextpost', $nextlink);


    }
}
add_action('init','update_portolio_metadata');
```

**Updated, checked and work**

```
function update_portolio_metadata(){
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio', // Only get the posts
            'post_status' => 'publish', // Only the posts that are published
            'posts_per_page'   => -1 // Get every post
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $previouslink = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false));
        $nextlink = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true));
            
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'previouspost', $previouslink);
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nextpost', $nextlink);
    endwhile;
}


add_action('init','update_portolio_metadata');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There functions works in the loop only. You can use [wp_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) instead of get_posts.

Your code should be like this:

```php
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $previouslink = get_previous_post_link();
    $nextlink = get_next_post_link();

    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'previouspost', $previouslink);
    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nextpost', $nextlink);
endwhile;
}
```

Comment: There are inside foreach loop.

Comment: not foreach loop, [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: I added code to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work. Finally it looks like up there, i have edited my post, check it please.

Comment: Im sorry, `previous_post_link` print the link I replaced to get_previous_post_link and added endwhile. Try again.

Comment: Oh, thanks, now we are very near.

I'm getting at field 
'<a href="https://testdomain.pl/portfolio/blatman-pl/" rel="prev">Testdomain.pl</a>'
Ho i can get only URL at it? - "https://testdomain.pl/portfolio/blatman-pl/"

Comment: see: https://codepad.co/snippet/get-only-the-url-of-the-previous-and-next-posts-in-wordpress